# How can I back out a change I made after a commit to master?

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

I have a project that I created in Visual Studio. I created a GIT repository, cloned it down to my computer and copied the VS project into it.  Now I am doing some learning on that test app.

I made a change to a file like this and did a commit:

```
MacBook:Test-master r$ git log
commit 690ef5d75cde00399d4e181993fdbb86e3c35273 (HEAD -> master, origin/master)
Author: rxx <yyyy>
Date:   Mon Feb 18 13:40:44 2019 +0800

    Added a test line
```

1. Is that normal for the password to be displayed in full view inside the ?
2. If I decide that I made a mistake and should not have done that commit is there a way that I can back it out from master?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Correct me if I'm wrong, when you're referring to password, do you mean this string - 690ef5d75cde00399d4e181993fdbb86e3c35273. This is not a password but unique hex identifier for the commit you made.

2) you can change the latest commit  with

> git commit --amend

This will not purge the commit but removes the reference from branch history. The original commit can still be accessed with 'git reflog'

If you haven't pushed the commit yet, you can also do

> git reset --hard HEAD^

to purge the latest commit altogether (also removes any further changes you made as well, so be careful)

Comment: Hi, Sorry the formatting hid the yyyy.  That was where the password was clearly visible.

Comment: Then, I'd suggest to do 'git reset --hard HEAD^' to purge the commit altogether. If you're referring to  'Author: rxx <yyyy>'. Normally, the yyyy here would be email address but i can be wrong

Comment: Thanks,I did the "it reset --hard HEAD^" and it removed the change locally.  But when in Visual Studio I tried to commit that change it told me "Cannot push non-fastforwardable reference"

Comment: This is most likely 'cause you already pushed your original commit. you can try doing a 'git pull origin <your branch>' as explained here - [link](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-non-fast-forward-errors/)